# Use PHP to get tags within a set tag id, class or other from a Website

Tags: php, html, parsing, tags, domdocument

I'm stuck. I'm trying to extract all html tags, their attributes and their text content that are inside a predefined tag from a remote website.

Example:
`<div id="its attributes">its text content</div>`

I can extract any tag using their id or class by using php's DOMDocument class, I just can't get my head around telling php to limit the return to that predefined tag.

Example:
`<div id="predefined">... return all this ...</div>`

I don't have any examples of code, As i've tried numerous options from numerous searches and all have return false results.

Can you please help?

UPDATE: I've found the answer here:
[PHP function to grab all links inside a <DIV> on remote site using scrape method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048070/php-function-to-grab-all-links-inside-a-div-on-remote-site-using-scrape-method)

Thanks to all that helped.

Comment: Do you need to use PHP or you can either use JavaScript (with jQuery)?

Comment: To be honest, I haven't given Javascript or jQuery any thought. However the use for Php would be preferable as i'm writing code to extract these tags to a mysql table.

Comment: Well, I think you should take a serious look at it (both). Your question is typically something really easy to do using jQuery, when you'll know the basics you won't even need help anymore to achieve what you're trying to

Comment: Thanks Oliboy50, i'll look into it. All suggestions are helpful. I should add, i'm trying to get these tags from a remote website. Is it still possible using jQuery/Javascript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048070/php-function-to-grab-all-links-inside-a-div-on-remote-site-using-scrape-method

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getElementById`, then access the `nodeValue`:

```
$doc->loadHTML('<html><body><div id="predefined">... return all this ...</div></body></html>');
$i = $doc->getElementById('predefined');
echo $i->nodeValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just if you want to learn about JavaScript and jQuery :

Assuming this HTML :

```
<div id="predefined">... return all this ...</div>
```

Use this JavaScript code (with jQuery) (I'm trying to make it simple but you'll do better if you learn well) :

```
// To get the content from a single HTML tag
var theID = "predefined";
var theContent = $("#" + theID).text(); // Or .html() if you want the whole content

// To POST the extracted content to your PHP page in order to write to your mySQL db
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://www.myapp.com/mypage.php",
    data: { id: theID, content: theContent },
    success: function(response){ // just in case you need a response from your PHP stuff
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

Then in your PHP "http://www.myapp.com/mypage.php" :

```
<?php
    $id = $_POST["id"];
    $content = $_POST["content"];

    // Note: Always sanitize posted data, to prevent injections and other malicious code.

    // Here you can save the data to your MySQL db

    echo "it worked!"; // This is the response that your "success" function will get in your Javascript code
?>
```

Well, I'm not sure this is the best answer for your special case, but anyway you really should learn JavaScript =)