# Identifying clicked link and passing the id to a function

Tags: javascript, php, html

I would like to call a function each time a link is clicked. In this function, I will then call the appropriate page. Without creating a function for each link, how could I identify the clicked link? Here is a mixure of javascript and php to show how I want to do.

```
<div>
  <ul><li><a id="address" href="clicked">address</a></li></ul>
  <ul><li><a id="about" href="clicked">about</a></li></ul>
</div>

<?php
    function clicked() {
       $theaddress = $("#address").isClicked(); //looking at a function like isClicked
       $theabout=  $("#about").isClicked(); //do the same thing in case the function exists

       if ($theaddress) {
         //call the address page
       }
       else if ($theabout) {
         // call the about page
       }
     }
?>
```

I would like to know if this is really possible. I know I could have a function for each link, but that looks like too many functions to me. So far this is what I got [from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25335891/use-php-to-get-tags-within-a-set-tag-id-class-or-other-from-a-website)

Comment: it looks to me like all you need do is call the appropriate page and put the php function at the top of that page ???? is there a reason for not doing it that way.

Comment: thanks but if I have to call the page directly, then there is no need for me to writte the function since all the stuffs I am checking are supposed to be checked before I call the page

Comment: What do you exactly need to do? When the user clicks address, then should a request be made to server and should your script at server know that user clicked address?

Comment: @MehulMohan address and about are just examples.. what I need to do is  know which link was clicked and then depending on the user type add some parameters to the request sent to the server

Comment: You've mixed the JavaScript and PHP in a way that just makes it a big collection of errors. What are you actually trying to achieve? Are you trying to get the information in JS or in PHP?

Comment: "what I need to do is know which link was clicked and then depending on the user type add some parameters to the request sent to the server" — Why don't you just encode them in the URLs for the two links in the first place?

Comment: So for that, obviously you need some javascript. You can't run PHP on frontend.

Comment: @Quentin I am trying to get the information in PHP basically. what but the javascript code I added in the first two lines is just to idea I am looking for, which is obviousily not great. what do you mean by encoding url. like urlencoding or uft-8 specification? why is it necessary?

Comment: @MehulMohan true... but in the case of back end the code will not be visible to the user and the calling of the page will be done after the checks. maybe server side javascript could do it..? thanks again..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget JavaScript. If you just want one PHP program to handle two links and for each link to pass a bit of identifying data, then just put that data in the URL.

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="clicked?id=address">address</a></li>
  <li><a href="clicked?id=about">about</a></li>
</ul>
```

… and then:

```
$clicked = $_GET['clicked'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `onClick` mouse event.

**inline:**
`<a href=# onClick="window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com'">HERE</a>`

**call a function (url inline):**

```
<a href=# onClick="redirect('http://www.google.com')">HERE</a>

<script>
    function redirect(key) {     
    window.location.href = key;
    }
</script>
```

**call a function (url inside):**

```
<a href=# onClick="redirect('a1')">HERE</a>  
<a href=# onClick="redirect('a2')">HERE</a>

<script>
    function redirect(key) {
    if (key == "a1") {  
    window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
    } else if (key == "a2") {
    window.location.href = 'http://images.google.com';
    } 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: thanks.. the problem is basically on how  to know/ differentiate whether about link or address link is clicked, when I am calling one function

Comment: thanks again but it is not working.. I also want to say that I am using links.. with button, I can use the post or get methods to know whether the button was set.  But I am not using forms in my case.

Comment: dont forget of let the javascript code inside `<script>` `</script>` tags.