# get link by specific search text using simple Html dom parser

Tags: php, html-parsing

i want to get a link by specific text in title, using simple html dom parser PHP

html code

```
<h3 class="title"><a href="0.html" class="title">  keyword1 </a></h3>
```

how to get link if title is "keyword1" ?

my code

```
$html = file_get_html($url);


foreach($html->find('h3[class=title]') as $e){

if(isset($e)){
foreach($e->find('keywords1') as $ee)

   foreach($html->find('a') as $eee){
 $d = $eee;




print_r ($d)."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP function to grab all links inside a <DIV> on remote site using scrape method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048070/php-function-to-grab-all-links-inside-a-div-on-remote-site-using-scrape-method)

Comment: how to show path of a link when a href format is <a href="0.html"> , not <a href="http://example.com/site/test/2444/0.html"/> ?

Comment: how does `url` look like?

Comment: echo substr($url, 0, strrpos($str, '/')) . '/' . $a->href;    output -> "0.html /0.html"

Comment: I was expecting output is http://example.com/site/{not known}/0.html

Comment: there was a typo. try now with url instead of str

Comment: work fine, thank you so much ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code  finds `a` tag containing `keyword1`

```
$html = file_get_html($url);
foreach($html->find('h3[class=title] a[plaintext*=keyword1]') as $a) 
   echo $a->href . "\n";  //  0.html
```

To sure that it is what you are looking for, you can additionally test that

```
trim($a->innertext) == 'keyword1'
```

UPD:

if I correcty understood what you want

```
echo substr($url, 0, strrpos($url, '/')) . '/' . $a->href;
```

Comment: wow great  work fine, thank you, but how to get full path of link 0.html ? this  show 0.html only

Comment: what do you mean as 'full path' ? This fragment of code don't give ability to understand context

Comment: path of link 0.html is "mydomain.com/site/test/0.html"  .possible to show this ? not only "0.html"

Comment: where are you taking `mydomain.com/site/test` from? if you know it just `echo "mydomain.com/site/test/" . $a->href;`

Comment: sorry I forgot, I have many folders in "mydomain.com/site/test/" like mydomain.com/site/test/2472/0.html" , "mydomain.com/site/test/2444/0.html" with the same name of html file "0.html" in each folder .

Comment: @vallez And how understand in what folder it is placed?

Comment: I want to search for "keyword1" in the html files in many folders, and I want to find the folder where the file is located, in your code is work, but not show folder, only show 0.html, not full domain path

Comment: how to show path of a link when a href format is <a href="0.html"> , not <a href="example.com/site/test/2444/0.html"/>; ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this method **preg_match_all**
http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php